# How to implement an HTTPS web server using esp8266 with nodemcu?

Tags: ssl, https, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm implementing a web server for access control and I need it to be encrypted (https).
I am using the LUA language with the nodemcu version 2.1.0 firmware and the modules file, gpio, http, mdns, net, node, struct, tmr, uart, wifi, tls

I have searched in many web pages but most use it in client mode, but I can not find or understand how to do this with an https page.

I have seen tls.createserver but it is in node.js.
Please if anyone can help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not yet possible: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1700#issuecomment-270756205

Comment: This has been possible in esp-open-rtos since 1 year. esp-open-rtos has an included, open-source mbedTLS library. Alternatively also packages the BearTLS library. (https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/tree/master/examples/tls_server, https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/tree/master/examples/tls_server_bearssl). Also has an example for an HTTP Server with static files and dynamic handlers, which can be easily ported to use mbedtls TLS sockets instead of plain TCP sockets. (https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/tree/master/examples/http_server)